# Chart.PlotArea.InsideHeight loses decimal digits

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub setPlotArea()
With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(1).Chart.PlotArea
    .InsideHeight = 110.2545648225413
End With
End Sub
```

When I apply the above code, I get 110. The decimal digits are lost.
I searched but could not solve.

Comment: `InsideHeight` property should be a double and accept the value you input. Do you do it exactly as you show us, or you have an intermediary variable, maybe wrongly declared (`As Long`), which would not be exactly the same? Do you fill the value according to another Function, Formula etc.?

Comment: I have used the above code exactly.

Comment: That value is in points and I'm assuming you can't have a fraction of a point.

Comment: How can you see the difference between the two such values (in Points)?

Comment: @ BigBen: I think that you can, since the property value is a `Double`...

Comment: @FaneDuru - when testing and manually adjusting the height, `Debug.Print` never returned a value with a fraction. Just because the return value is a `Double` doesn't mean that it actually returns a number with a decimal.

Comment: @ BigBen:  `Debug.Print` maybe, but `InsideHeight` should accept a double, I think...

Comment: It does accept a double. My guess is it silently discards the fraction part.

Comment: @ BigBen: This can be true. I asked him how he can see the difference. I am curious what he will answer...

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: To do what 'this'?

Comment: A point is 1/72 inch... How do you see the difference, and why is important? Just curious...

Comment: I have two slides. Both slides have one chart. And I wanted to copy the position of plot area from chart 1 from slide 1 to the position of the plot area of chart 2 from slide 2. As my macro forgoing the decimal points, both chart are not in lined. While slide show, i can see the difference.

Comment: Please let me know if its unclear.

Comment: What is unclear is the fact that you do not write the value like in the above code. You somehow copy it... If my understanding is correct, can you also show us this copying sequence? Besides this aspect, `InsideHeight` is not related to a position. It is like the property name reflect, a dimension size... Do you want saying that the bottom is aligned, but the Top not?

Comment: PlotArea_InsideHeight = shp.Chart.PlotArea.InsideHeight

Comment: PlotArea_InsideWidth = shp.Chart.PlotArea.InsideWidth

Comment: Global PlotArea_InsideWidth As Double

Comment: please find the above code

Comment: This set exactly what is to be set, I think. I am sure that both charts `InsideHeight` is identic. But, ***like I said above***, the position of the chart is not related to`InsideHeight`... It is a necessary condition (maybe), but not enough. Try using the chart `.Top` and  `.Left`, to position both of them.

Comment: Yup, finally i made the code using chart.height and chart.width. Thanks